# karma-html2js does not create window.__html__

Tags: javascript, karma-runner

So I have verified `window.__karma__.files` contains my .html files (karma files config is picking them up). If I have html2js disabled, files show up as file.html in `window.__karma__.files`. If I enable html2js, files show up as file.html.js in `window.__karma__.files`. Either way, `window.__html__` is undefined.

Also using karma-jasmine and karma-requirejs, attempting to use karma-fixture but this is a show stopper for that.

I am not using angular, and I am not using ng-html2js. I have log_debug enabled in my karma config, and the preprocessor is reporting "Processing" for all of my .html files.

I'm at a total loss here. Anyone seen this before?

Answer (score 2):

Turns out the issue is in karma.conf.

`files: [
   ...,
   {pattern: '**/*.html', included: false},
   ...
 ]`

Does not work. I copied my pattern from my js files that are not included (because I load them via requirejs), and left included set to false there. Apparently included should be true (default) or the js-ified file (with the `window.__html__ = ...` code at the top) is never executed.